# Getting notification when active window changes

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, hook

I am trying to get my program to get the current active window title when the focus is changed. I have the following CALLBACK:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK windowChangeHook(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (wParam == HCBT_SETFOCUS || lParam == HCBT_SETFOCUS)
        cout << GetActiveWindowTitle();

    return(CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam));
}
```

And I am trying to hook WH_CBT as follows:

```
HHOOK hhkWindowChange = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, windowChangeHook, 0, 0);
```

Maybe I am just stupid but it isn't working as intended, anyone have an idea why?

**EDIT:**
It doesn't seem like the program is detecting the window changes at all, I have tried changing the code to this to no avail:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK windowChangeHook(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (nCode == HCBT_ACTIVATE || nCode == HCBT_SETFOCUS)
        cout << "TEST";

    return(CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam));
}
```

Comment: _"...but it isn't working as intended.."_  What isn't working: the setting of the hook;  the hook getting called; not detecting focus change?  Is you hook implemented in DLL you need to do this if you want to detect windows not belonging to your app?

Comment: Sorry should've been more specific Richard, the it doesn't seem like it is detecting the window change.

Comment: Of course not. You are guessing how to use an API. That's not going to work out that way. Read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644977.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not handling the `WH_CBT` callback correctly.

Per the [CBTProc callback function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644977.aspx) documentation:

> nCode [in]
>   Type: int
>
> **The code that the hook procedure uses to determine how to process the message.** If `nCode` is less than zero, the hook procedure must pass the message to the `CallNextHookEx` function without further processing and should return the value returned by `CallNextHookEx`. This parameter can be one of the following values.
>
> ...
>
> HCBT_SETFOCUS
>   9
>   A window is about to receive the keyboard focus.

> wParam [in]
>   Type: WPARAM
>
> **Depends on the `nCode` parameter**. For details, see the following Remarks section.

> lParam [in]
>   Type: LPARAM
>
> **Depends on the `nCode` parameter**. For details, see the following Remarks section.

> The following table describes the `wParam` and `lParam` parameters for each `HCBT_` hook code.
>
> ...
>
> HCBT_SETFOCUS
>   wParam: Specifies the handle to the window gaining the keyboard focus.
>   lParam: Specifies the handle to the window losing the keyboard focus.

You are looking for the `HCBT_SETFOCUS` value in the wrong parameter.  You are also retrieving the title of the wrong window, since the input focus has not actually switched windows yet.

Your callback should look more like this instead (assuming your callback is implemented in a DLL, which is required to detect global events, which also means you need separate 32bit and 64bit DLLs on a 64bit system. This is explained in the [`SetWindowsHookEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990.aspx) documentation):

```
LRESULT CALLBACK windowChangeHook(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (nCode == HCBT_SETFOCUS)
    {
        HWND hwnd = (HWND) wParam;
        // retreive and use the title of hwnd as needed...
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

That being said, you should consider using [`SetWinEventHook()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373640.aspx) instead, which does not have the DLL requirement if you use the hook "out-of-context":

> The callback function is not mapped into the address space of the process that generates the event. Because the hook function is called across process boundaries, the system must queue events. Although this method is asynchronous, events are guaranteed to be in sequential order. For more information, see [Out-of-Context Hook Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373611.aspx).

> EVENT_OBJECT_FOCUS
>   0x8005
>
> **An object has received the keyboard focus**. The system sends this event for the following user interface elements: list-view control, menu bar, pop-up menu, switch window, tab control, tree view control, and **window object**. Server applications send this event for their accessible objects.
>
> **The `hwnd` parameter of the `WinEventProc` callback function identifies the window that receives the keyboard focus**.

For example:

```
void CALLBACK windowChangeHook(HWINEVENTHOOK hWinEventHook, DWORD event, HWND hwnd, LONG idObject, LONG idChild, DWORD dwEventThread, DWORD dwmsEventTime)
{
    // retreive and use the title of hwnd as needed...
}

HWINEVENTHOOK hEventHook = SetWinEventHook(EVENT_OBJECT_FOCUS, EVENT_OBJECT_FOCUS, NULL, &windowChangeHook, 0, 0, WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT);
...
UnhookWinEvent(hEventHook);
```

Answer (score 3):

- You are not checking the return value from `SetWindowsHookEx`!
- `windowChangeHook` needs to be in a DLL with its `HMODULE` in the `hMod` parameter.
- The `HCBT_*` values are passed in the `nCode` parameter!

You could also try using [`SetWinEventHook`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373640(v=vs.85).aspx) instead...